futex for a file in /tmp directory: operation not permitted
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

$ uname -r
5.15.0-125-generic

I am trying to work with coq theorem proof assistant installed with snap using Emacs and proof general. Unfortunately, I got an error. After investigating it with strace I found out that the error is caused by futex system call "permission denied" when the program tries to process a file in /tmp directory:
$ strace coqdep /tmp/ProofGeneral-coqofYWUP.v

trying to imitate what proof general does and got the following:

--- SIGURG {si_signo=SIGURG, si_code=SI_TKILL, si_pid=123729, si_uid=1000} ---
rt_sigreturn({mask=[]})                 = 22
getpid()                                = 123729
tgkill(123729, 123751, SIGURG)          = 0
getpid()                                = 123729
tgkill(123729, 123750, SIGURG)          = 0
futex(0x55610de9d158, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x55610de9d250, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=100000}) = 0
getpid()                                = 123729
tgkill(123729, 123751, SIGURG)          = 0
getpid()                                = 123729
tgkill(123729, 123750, SIGURG)          = 0
futex(0x55610de9d158, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
getpid()                                = 123729
tgkill(123729, 123751, SIGURG)          = 0
futex(0x55610de9d158, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
epoll_pwait(4, [], 128, 0, NULL, 0)     = 0
futex(0xc000100948, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
futex(0x55610de9d250, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, {tv_sec=0, tv_nsec=100000}) = 0
close(3)                                = 0
futex(0x55610de9bc28, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
epoll_pwait(4, [{EPOLLOUT, {u32=1967093352, u64=140516117149288}}], 128, 0, NULL, 0) = 1
epoll_pwait(4, [{EPOLLOUT, {u32=1967093352, u64=140516117149288}}], 128, -1, NULL, 0) = 1
epoll_pwait(4, [], 128, 0, NULL, 191668) = 0
futex(0x55610de9bc28, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
epoll_pwait(4, [{EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT, {u32=1967093592, u64=140516117149528}}], 128, 0, NULL, 0) = 1
epoll_pwait(4, [{EPOLLOUT, {u32=1967093352, u64=140516117149288}}], 128, -1, NULL, 0) = 1
epoll_pwait(4, [], 128, 0, NULL, 191668) = 0
epoll_pwait(4, [{EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT, {u32=1967093352, u64=140516117149288}}], 128, -1, NULL, 0) = 1
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/user/1000/bus"}, msg_namelen=112->21, msg_iov=[{iov_base="l\2\1\1'\0\0\0l\4\0\0-\0\0\0", iov_len=16}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 16
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/user/1000/bus"}, msg_namelen=112->21, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\5\1u\0\2\0\0\0\6\1s\0\6\0\0\0:1.155\0\0\10\1g\0\1o\0\0"..., iov_len=48}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 48
recvmsg(3, {msg_name={sa_family=AF_UNIX, sun_path="/run/user/1000/bus"}, msg_namelen=112->21, msg_iov=[{iov_base="\"\0\0\0/org/freedesktop/systemd1/jo"..., iov_len=39}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC}, MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = 39
futex(0xc000100948, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 1
recvmsg(3, {msg_namelen=112}, MSG_CMSG_CLOEXEC) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/123729/cgroup", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 8
epoll_ctl(4, EPOLL_CTL_ADD, 8, {EPOLLIN|EPOLLOUT|EPOLLRDHUP|EPOLLET, {u32=1967093592, u64=140516117149528}}) = -1 EPERM (Operation not permitted)
read(8, "13:cpuset:/\n12:rdma:/\n11:memory:"..., 4096) = 547
close(8)                                = 0
write(6, "\0", 1)                       = 1
futex(0x55610de9bc28, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 0, NULL) = 0
epoll_pwait(4, [], 128, 0, NULL, 0)     = 0
epoll_pwait(4,  <unfinished ...>)       = ?
*** Error: /tmp/ProofGeneral-coqofYWUP.v: No such file or directory
+++ exited with 1 +++


Unfortunately, I am not qualified enough to understand what causes permission denied for the system call. I even made the permissions 777 for this file, it didn't help.

After I copied the file to my home dir, it started to work:


$ cp /tmp/ProofGeneral-coqofYWUP.v ~/aaa.v
$ coqdep ~/aaa.v
home/usr345/aaa.vo /home/usr345/aaa.glob /home/usr345/aaa.v.beautified /home/usr345/aaa.required_vo: /home/usr345/aaa.v 
/home/usr345/aaa.vio: /home/usr345/aaa.v 


/tmp as it's name implies is temporary.  It's owned by root for process and socket management, among other things.  As such the futex and write call fail because only root can open and write files there.  Either precede the run with sudo or move it to your home directory as you discovered.

@eyoung100 No, /tmp is world writeable, so anyone can open a file there. The problem might be the "safety" feature added on "t" attributes to prevent non-owners of a file from changing things.  There is a way to set the old behavior, but that introduces a security risk -- better just use $HOME for your temporary files.

@ubfan1 Thanks, I had to google that and found this SuperUser Answer.  I retract my erroneous comment that is being left here so  all the comments make sense.

It seems that it is impossible to allow access to /tmp directory for coq-prover snap. Because the authors of the package didn't add system-files interface into it.
When I tried to enable it, it gave an error:
# snap connect coq-prover:system-files
error: snap "coq-prover" has no plug named "system-files"

To fix the issue change the temporary directory name to a subdirectory of your home dir in Emacs configs:
(setq temporary-file-directory (concat (getenv "HOME") "/tmp"))


Or, perhaps better, export the TMPDIR variable to the variety of
programs that need temporary files, for example in ~/.bash_login
export TMPDIR=$HOME/tmp
and then use getenv "TMPDIR" in the temporary-file-directory.

snap restrict use confined environment when it use application so /tmp can cause problem even with your chmod 777, you could instead simply use the snap directory by copying the file like this
cp /tmp/ProofGeneral-coqofYWUP.v ~/snap/coq/
coqdep ~/snap/coq/ProofGeneral-coqofYWUP.v

You could also simply use a non confined package environment
sudo apt update
sudo apt install coq


The unfortunate thing is that the file /tmp/ProofGeneral-... is generated and ran automatically by ProofGeneral module from Emacs. I don't know, how to change the dir yet. And the version of coq in apt is 8.11, while in snap it is 8.18. It is not critical for me, but it would be better to use a newer version. Is it possible to disable the /tmp restrictions imposed by snap?

Have you tried installing it with the classic flag like sudo snap install coq --classic . with this flag it will disable most of the sandboxing

No, doesn't work: Warning: flag --classic ignored for strictly confined snap coq-prover.
